# How to using again string when has explode

Tags: php

I have a sample code:

```
$string = 'abc def ghi abc des abc xyz';
$arr = explode('abc', $string);
print_r(arr);
```

result is

```
Array ( 
      [0] => 
      [1] => def ghi 
      [2] => des 
      [3] => xyz 
      )
```

But i want to keep "abc" in the resulting segments like this:

```
Array ( 
      [0] => 
      [1] => abc def ghi 
      [2] => abc des 
      [3] => abc xyz 
      )
```

How to fix it ?

Comment: prepend abc to each element in the array (note: the first element needs special handling)

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
$string = 'abc def ghi abc des abc xyz';
$string = str_replace('abc', '%abc', $string);
$arr = explode('%', $string);
print_r(arr);
```

This is under the assumption that your original string won't have the % character. If it will, replace % in the code above with something that certainly won't appear in your original string.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with `array_filter()` :

```
function myExplode($var) {
    foreach($var as $key=>$value) {
        if($key>0) {
            $var[$key] = $var[0]." ".$value;
        }
    }
    return $var;
}
$string = "abc def ghi abc des abc xyz";
print_r(array_filter(explode("abc",$string), "myExplode"));
```

Comment: This will fail, explode requires two parameters.

Comment: you *either* have array_filter *or* a loop.. this combination doesn't make sense

Answer (score 0):

```
$string = 'abc def ghi abc des abc xyz';
$arr = explode('abc', $string);
$new_arr = array_map(function($v){
return 'abc' . $v;
}, $arr);

print_r($new_arr);
```

OR for backward compatibility, you'll need to use the create_function as anonymous functions are not supported in earlier php versions:

```
$delimiter = 'abc';
$string = 'test';

$func = create_function('$v', 'global $delimiter; return ($v ? $delimiter . $v : false);');

if(strstr($string, $delimiter)):
$arr = explode($delimiter, $string);
$new_arr = array_map($func, $arr);
endif;

print_r($new_arr);
```

Comment: His example contains 'abc' in the string, if the string was to change you would obviously perform a check prior to the explode.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`preg_split()`](http://php.net/preg_split) with a (non-captured) [lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) condition to split the string before each occurance of "abc":

Code:

```
$subject = 'abc def ghi abc des abc xyz';
$result = preg_split('/ ?(?=abc)/', $subject, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
```

Result:

```
Array ( 
     [0] => 'abc def ghi'
     [1] => 'abc des'
     [2] => 'abc xyz'
)
```

(I guess it's in your interest to not have the first empty element captured?)

Answer (score -1):

```
 <?php
 $string = 'abc def ghi abc des abc xyz';
 $arr = explode('abc', $string);
 foreach($arr as $k=>$v) {
   $k = 'abc ' . $v;
 }
 print_r($arr);
 ?>
```

Comment: the question has a specific `$string` and so does the answer.